# find the source of an app on my tab3

Tags: google-play-store

It has an Android robot with a cloud over his head with the letters dlna in the cloud? I downloaded an app from google play and can't find the source to look it up to figure how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Settings` menu look for the `App` section. From there you will be able to select it and find information about it along with the package name.